# What is the difference between os.devnull and subprocess.pipe?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I've been trying out how *not* to print shell outputs from Python's `subprocess.call()` by assigning `open(os.devnull, 'w')` and `subprocess.PIPE` to the `stdout` value:

```
subprocess.call(command, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), shell=True)
```

and

```
subprocess.call(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Both these lines execute the shell command stored in the `command` variable discreetly i.e. without outputting on the terminal. However, I don't know the difference between the two. I am new to using `subprocess`.

/ogs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method is to redirect the standard output to a file (`/dev/null` in POSIX), while the second one is to build a `PIPE` to redirect the output to a specific stream.

The official definition of `subprocess.PIPE` referred from command help():     *"This module allows you to spawn processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes."*

I would say this method is like: we just put something in a message queue(memory) for a while for later use. But `subprocess.call` just return the status code. It seems you cannot refer the return value for `subprocess.call(command, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), shell=True)` so that you cannot refer the value by `subprocess.call(command, stdin=the_stdout, shell=True)`. It is hard to build a connection between two commands.

Based on the info in this article: http://blog.acipo.com/running-shell-commands-in-python/

Also Python 2.7 Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

It is recommended that we may use `Popen` with communicate()

`Popen` is an advanced class provided by Python 3.
There is a good resource about this: https://stackabuse.com/pythons-os-and-subprocess-popen-commands/

Comment: hi, thanks for this comprehensive answer and for the corresponding references.

/ogs

Comment: My pleasure. Could u please give me one score for my answer? appreciate.

Comment: unfortunately my rep is still too low for me to increase your score, but i will increase the score as soon as i hit 15 rep. also chosen your answer as the best answer. you're welcome. /ogs

Comment: @CandyCrusher Thanks for the answer. I've tried my best to edit it as much as I can. However, I'm still a bit confused in *"It seems you cannot refer the return value for `subprocess.call(command, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), shell=True)` ... It is hard to build a connection between two commands."* Could you please paraphrase these two sentences? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`devnull` is a point to `/dev/null` in Linux. When you write to `/dev/null`, it will discard everything received.

`pipe` has two ends, when you write to one end, the other `pipe` will receive the message you wrote.

Comment: Could you please add more detailed info on why devnull will discard everything received. thx.

Comment: @CandyCrusher it points to a file in the OS that discards everything it receives. that's why jokes like "Complaints get sent to /dev/null" work